# How to access data of controls inside usercontrol in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a user control dynamically which contains dropdowns'. Loading User control is iterated 'I' times according to the condition. Now, I need to access the dropdowns' selected item. I have created an accessor function to get the dropdown selected values, but it is giving me the default value, which is "00" of the drop-down.

If someone needs additional Information to solve my problem, 
kindly ask me.

Adding user control dynamically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

     //DailyControl is a userControl
      DailyControl w1 = (DailyControl)LoadControl("~/DailyControl.ascx");
     //InputPanel is a panel where user control is added.                   
       InputPanel.Controls.Add(w1);
    }
```

DailyControl.ascx

```
Select the Time:


<asp:DropDownList ID="clock" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="am" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="pm" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

DailyControl.ascx.cs // accessor function to get the dropdown

```
public string Clock
{
    get
    {
        return clock.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create property on user control to access dropdown's selected value. Once property is created, just access your user control on page using for loop and access property.

Comment: Please specify how to create property on user control

Comment: You have already property called `Clock` so when you access it, you will get selected item. Change your return statement to: `return clock.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();`

Comment: Not working, clock returns the first value of dropdown list, not the selected value.

Comment: Try to debug and check.You need to iterate with all user controls to get values. So you should select proper user control's value to get it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of add controls dinamically, you can use a Repeater on aspx page.
In the Repeater you can bind a `DropDownList` (or a control containing the DropDownList) and get

```
myDropDownList.SelectedValue
```

(or SelectedItem)